# Mongodb positional operator is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

When I am trying to update just "title", it is working fine, but if I am trying to update the nested object in the array, it is not working.

Data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waJ4j.png)

Working:

```
const restaurant = await Restaurant.update(
    {_id: '60e6828e4992a2979fa0ba3e'},
    {$set: {title: "Hello}},
  );
```

Not working:

```
const restaurant = await Restaurant.update(
    {_id: '60e6828e4992a2979fa0ba3e', 'grades.grade': 85},
    {$set: {'grades.$.grade': 0}},
  );
```

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/caFBz-lx8dQ

Use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation

```
db.collection.update(
 {},
 { $set: { "grades.$[elem].grade": 0 }},
 { arrayFilters: [ {"elem.grade": 85 } ]}
)
```

Comment: That is kind of weird. Your code is still not working in my project. I think something wrong with mongoose since I am using it.